# Is it possible to check if an audio is playing in my computer with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So basically, I want to make a code by which I would create a new file every time a new song or audio is being played in my computer.

So imagine this situation, I use Groove Music (the default music player on windows 10) to listen to some songs. And whenever I change the song (not necessarily to be on purpose) a new file creates (assuming that my code is running) which looks something like this

```json
Song Name: Name of the song
Artist Name: Name of the artist
Album Name: Name of the album
```

So how can I make it ?
By the way, I have a decent knowledge on Node.js and JavaScript so you need not to spend much time on explaining the simpler things.